# Combining different machine learning algorithms with boosting in R

Tags: r, adaboost

Is there package for R to boost different algorithms? For example Random Forest and neural networks. As I understand, packages `ada` and `gbm` can only boost Decision Trees.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the packages

- `caret` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html
- `C50` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/index.html
- `GAMBoost` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GAMBoost/index.html
- `mboost` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mboost/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to manual `C50` can "Fit classification **tree models** or rule-based models using Quinlan’s C5.0 algorithm". I'm looking for algorithm which can use any weak predictor.

Comment: Do you mean `best` function from `caret` package? I'm not sure that it is boosting, it returns only one predictor.

Comment: You may consider joining the machine-learning site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning